Only get current scene camera value once
This has wasted too much time, and I need to get some help.
I've created a program which has multiple graphs -- one of them is a threejs plot. As the user changes the orientation of the 3d plot, I need to save the current camera orientation to ensure that the orientation is retained after the sliders alter the plot. I seem to have the correct logic, but the following code only seems to save the current camera orientation once. Every call thereafter, just gives me the same camera orientation save from the first time. I'm not sure if this is a known issue -- I can provide much more code to provide further context if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
// Capture and save the camera state each time the user changes the orientation
document.getElementById('threejs-plot').on('plotly_relayout', function(eventdata) {
        const sceneLayout = document.getElementById('threejs-plot').layout.scene;
        if (sceneLayout.camera) {
            currentCamera = sceneLayout.camera;
        }
    });


I don't think (or I'm not aware) we can use plotly.js with a three.js plot, and conversely. We definitely need more context, please provide a mwe so we can reproduce the issue.
